# UPSERT REST Api creates new record because of space(%20) urlencoding

Tags: rest-api, custom-field, rest, upsert, externalid

I'm currently trying to use the [salesforce UPSERT endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm).

The ExternalId that I'm using contains a space, like so:

```
North America_12345
```

so my URL looks like:

```
/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/MyObject__c/MyObject_ExternalID__c/North America_20913
```

The problem here is that if the ExternalId already exists it is created again, but with the ExternalID like:

```
North%20America_12345
```

so now I have two "duplicate" records.

I've tried passing it on the url like

- `North%20America_12345`
- `North America_12345`
- `North+America_12345`

but the result is the same. Is there anyway to get around this using this same endpoint?

Comment: how are you calling the api? Works fine for me with `%20` for the space when testing through workbench.